# Can't run Ripple3D action of cocos2d javascript sprite in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, cocos2d-js

I am trying to run a `Ripple3D` action:

```
var mySprite = new cc.Sprite(res.SPRITE);
mySprite.runAction(cc.ripple3D(5.0, cc.size(400,400), cc.p(200,200), 50, 4, 100));
```

But I get this:

> Uncaught TypeError: this._gridNodeTarget.getGridRect is not a function

This has to be specific to `cc.size()` or `ripple3D` because everything is fine for an action like `MoveBy` or `RotateBy`.

I am using cocos2d-javascript 3.0. Compiling the cocos console for Web. Testing on Google Chrome, Mac OSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this effect before but looking at the EffectsTest.js in the sample folder of the engine I see they use a NodeGrid to do the effect.

```
var node = new cc.Node();
var nodeGrid = new cc.NodeGrid();
nodeGrid.addChild(node);
nodeGrid.runAction(cc.ripple3D(duration, cc.size(32, 24), cc.p(winSize.width / 2, winSize.height / 2), 240, 4, 160););
this.addChild(nodeGrid);
// back gradient
var gradient = new cc.LayerGradient(cc.color(0, 0, 0, 255), cc.color(98, 99, 117, 255));
node.addChild(gradient);

// back image
var bg = new cc.Sprite(s_back3);
bg.x = winSize.width / 2;
bg.y = winSize.height / 2;
node.addChild(bg);
```

The code speaks a bit for itself so I hope it helps you.